# Start wallpaper service from shell

Tags: android, shell, service

I've tried several variations to no avail:

```
am startservice android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService
am startservice android.service.wallpaper
am startservice -n android.service.wallpaper/android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService
am startservice -n android.service.wallpaper/.WallpaperService
```

all respond with something like:

```
Starting service: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] pkg=android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService }
Error: Not found; no service started.
```

How do I properly tell android to start this particular service?

----------- END QUESTION ----------------

WHY do I want to do this?

On the Nexus Q the Wallpaper Manager service is not running. I have a launcher running, I can select a wallpaper from the gallery, but when it goes to apply the wallpaper, I see this in logcat:

WallpaperManager: "WallPaper Service not running"

I figure this is either because it is left out of the Q altogether or it is just never started.

To troubleshoot this I want to start the service manually from the shell on a device that has working wallpaper - my Nexus 7. I want to do this just to be sure I'm using the correct command, and then try to manually start the service on the Q and see what happens.

Comment: WallpaperService is a class which is extended by Live Wallpapers, So above method does not work. Though i am not too sure about the log you are getting